# How to query records one table by checking record field in another?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables:

**TableOne**

| id | name | orgId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id-1 | One | org-1 |
| id-2 | Two | org-1 |
| id-3 | Three | org-1 |
| id-4 | Four | org-2 |

**TableTwo**

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| id-1 | Ok |
| diff-id-1 | Ok |
| diff-id-2 | Ok |

How to write a query to retrieve records from `TableOne` where `orgId=org-1` and `userId` **is not present** in `TableTwo`?

In JS I would write a if as a two for loops.

I wrote the beginning of a statement:

```
SELECT * from schema.TableOne
WHERE orgId = 'org-1'
```

But I have no idea how to check `TableOne` id to `TableTwo` id.

The result should be:

| id | name | orgId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id-2 | Two | org-1 |
| id-3 | Three | org-1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` with a subquery:

```
select t1.* from tableone t1 where t1.orgid='org-1' 
    and not exists (select 1 from tabletwo t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an left outer join on the user id with table2two.
The ON clause is used for the join.
then add a where clause where you filter for for orgid = "org-1" , and you filter out any rows where there is amatch in TableTwo, that is done by only inlcuding row where TableTwo.Id is null

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM TableOne t1
LEFT JOIN TableTwo t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.Id
WHERE t1.orgid = 'org-1'
AND t2.Id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query

select *
from #TableOne
where orgId='org-1'
and ID  not in
(select ID from #TableTwo)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H44f.png)